Why does my microphone only records white noise in CentOS 9?
After upgrading my Linux kernel I have noticed the microphone records only noise. Of course I have checked my microphone is working in Windows but not in my current CentOS Stream 9.
Here are my system information:
$ uname -a
Linux localme 5.14.0-503.el9.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Aug 22 17:03:23 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lspci -vv | grep -i audio
05:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 470/480 / 570/580/590]
07:00.4 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller

$ aplay --list-devices
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [LG HDR WFHD]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC897 Analog [ALC897 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

$ /sbin/lsmod | grep snd
snd_seq_dummy          12288  0
snd_hrtimer            12288  1
snd_hda_codec_realtek   208896  1
snd_hda_codec_generic   114688  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_scodec_component    20480  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     94208  1
snd_hda_intel          61440  4
snd_intel_dspcfg       40960  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_intel_sdw_acpi     16384  1 snd_intel_dspcfg
snd_hda_codec         225280  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core          155648  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_seq               131072  7 snd_seq_dummy
snd_seq_device         16384  1 snd_seq
snd_pcm               192512  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
snd_timer              53248  3 snd_seq,snd_hrtimer,snd_pcm
snd                   159744  20 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm
soundcore              16384  1 snd

